# Printing macro from an array

Tags: c, arrays, macros, header-files

```
#define ________    0x0
#define _______X    0x1
#define ______X_    0x2
#define ______XX    0x3
#define _____X__    0x4
```

I have created macros to store a few sets of characters as integer values in the .h file as shown above so as to make the .h file usable in other files.

If I include this .h file in any other .c file containing char arrays such as `ch[] = {________,_______X}` is there anyway for me to print the actual sets of characters i.e "**____**" for ch[0] and "_______X" for ch[1].  When I try to print it prints the char value for the corresponding integer values i.e 0 and 1.  Please let me know what command I can use to print the same.

Comment: You can reconstruct the string of `_`s and `X`s. You cannot retrieve the macro name at run time.

Comment: You should learn that names starting with two underscores are reserved for the implementation for any purpose.  Using names like that leaves you open to problems.  Plus, it is painful to implement binary notation in underscores and X's.  You could use gaming theory for tic-tac-toe (nought's and crosses), and use 'O' (letter) in place of underscore; OOOOOOOO and OOOOOOOX etc.

Answer (score 1):

A character is, by definition, a single character. Therefore, printing a single character such as 0x2 will never print several characters such as "_ _ _ _ _ _ X _". The way you'd do this is by creating an array of char * (strings in C are char *) rather an array of char. As in,

```
char **mystrings = {"________", "_______X", "______X_", etc.}
```

Then, you can use

```
printf("%s", mystrings[______X_]);
```

which will print

```
______X_
```

Answer (score 0):

You are representing numbers in a "binary" notation ( _ stands for 0 and X stands for 1). 
Since positive integer numbers are stored in memory in their exact binary representation, you can use the bit operators >> << and & to obtain the succesive bits.

Finally, for each bit, you can do something like that:

```
    putchar( bit? 'X': '_');
```

This sentence asks if your bit is 1 or 0. If it is equal to 1, then a character 'X' is printed, else, '_' is printed.

I left to you the details of writting the (iterative) algorithm to find the subsequent bits of a given number.

Comment: Thanks pablo1977.. I will use the binary operations as suggested.. :-)